# Including a complete HTML page in a PHP variable

Tags: php

I require to store a complete HTML page into a **PHP variable**

For ex. In my PHP page I have:

```
$myhtml_file="<html>  <body> <p> Phone: [Phone]</p> </body>      
    <\html>" //I want to store my HTML file into this php variable.


$phoneNo="090990"
$myhtml_file = preg_replace("/\[Phone\]/",$phoneNo,$myhtml_file );
```

Please provide me a solution on how can I store a **complete HTML file** in `$myhtml_file`.

I tried `include()` and `require()` but they do not fulfill my purpose as `preg_replace` doesn't replace value at `[Phone]`.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Use `file_get_contents()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question I dont know what exactly you want to do but here are some similiar cases ;)

If you want to include file you have separate ways:

```
1) include("myfile.html"); // Include
2) include "myfile.html"; // Include
3) $file = file_get_contents("myfile.html");
```

Or if you want to change every [Phone] in your page with your phone number its also easy:

```
$phoneNumber = "090990";
$email = "free@mail.com";
$replace = Array(
"[Phone]" => $phoneNumber,
"[Email]" => $email,
);
$file = file_get_contents("myfile.html");
$file = strtr($file, $replace);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `file_get_contents` to get the contents of your file.Use the code below

```
<?php
$myhtml_file=file_get_contents('test.html'); // will store all the content of html file
?>
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

Try storing all HTML data in separate file `(Normalize way)`. and run `file_get_contents (file_name )`  that will read entire file into String. Code will go like this:

```
$myhtml_file = file_get_contents(myFile.html) // Reads entire file into String
$phoneNo = "090990";
$myhtml_file = preg_replace("/\[Phone\]/",$phoneNo,$myhtml_file );
```